# PCManFM Icon not showing properly in lxde

Tags: pcmanfm

As you can see, the icons in the toolbar are not showing properly, but when I hover the mouse on the icon, it displays just fine. This is quite annoying and I was wondering if it is a sign that my system is compromised (hacked)

1. is this normal
2. how to fix it ?

[image]

[image]

Config : Lubuntu 18.04 LTS
everything is default

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: That doesn't look like a stock LXDE or PCManFM. Is it some theme you added? And, nah... It's almost certainly not an indicator of hacking or malware. You're (likely) just fine there. We can maybe get it resolved for you but we'll need more data like answering @OrganicMarble's question with the output of `lsb_release -a` and `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` added to your post by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1302070/edit) it.

Comment: I am using Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, everythig is default. second command returns LXDE. It only happens in that particular place, every other icon and software on my system is fine.

Comment: what happens if you change panel theme, overall theme or icons theme?

Comment: changing the icons didn't resolve the issue. So far, changing the theme did resolve it. By theme I mean the widget style in the 'widget' tab of the look and feel control panel